# In GWT 2.5, how do I populate multiple parts of a cell based up AbstractCell

Tags: gwt

I have a class ContactCell based on AbstractCell.
It has two Labels and one Image (defined in GWT 2.5's UiBinder).

How do I Column.addColumn() to add a this custom cell to a CellTable?

And If so, how do I use the method getValue() to populate the fields of ContactCell when getValue() only returns simple values (such as String).

```
Column<Contact, String> column = new Column<Contact, String>(
    new ContactCell()) {
  @Override
  public String getValue(Contact object) {
    return object... CAN ONLY RETURN ONE VALUE. HOW TO POPULATE 2 LABELS & IMAGE?
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the cell based on `AbstractCell` is defined using `UiBinder` then it's not currently `(GWT 2.5`) possible to add such cells to a `CellTable`.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the render string by overridding the onrender mathod of the cell as follows.

Assuming 2 labels and a image can be computed from the value returned by getValue mathod.

```
ContactCell contactCell = new ContactCell()
{
    @Override
    public void render( com.google.gwt.cell.client.Cell.Context context, SafeHtml value, SafeHtmlBuilder sb )
    {

    // do value check and compute label1 and label2 and calso compute the image path.       

    sb.appendHtmlConstant( "<label>LABEL1</label>" +"<label>LABEL2</label>"+"<image></image>" )
    }
});


Column<Contact, String> column = new Column<Contact, String>( contactCell ) 
{
  @Override
  public String getValue(Contact object) 
  {
    return object... CAN ONLY RETURN ONE VALUE. HOW TO POPULATE 2 LABELS & IMAGE?
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use an `IdentityColumn` instead of a normal `Column`  (will pass through the entire Contact object) or you use a normal `Column` like this:

```
Column<Contact, String[]> column = new Column<Contact, String[]>(
    new ContactCell()) {
  @Override
  public String[] getValue(Contact object) {
    String[] retvalue = new String[2];
    retvalue[0] = "SOMETHING";
    retvalue[1] = "SOME OTHER THING";
    return retvalue;
  }
};
```